# How to parse "20,54" as float in js?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a string like `"20,54"` into a float like `20.54` but with `parseFloat()` it is only returning `20` in this example:

```
this.Amount = parseFloat(order.Amount);
```

where `order.Amount` is `"20,54"`.

How can i solve this?

Comment: why would you store an "amount" value as a string in the first place? anyway, question is not about angular.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the reason is that valid js float format is number with point. to convert that you could try to replace comma with point

```
this.Amount = parseFloat(order.Amount.replace(',', '.'));
```

Answer (score -1):

This code should solve your problem.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>the number is : {{amount}}</h1>
  <button (click)="convert2Float()"> Click to Float</button>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  amount: string|number = '20,54';

  convert2Float() {
    this.amount = parseFloat(this.amount.replace(',','.'))
  }

}
```

[Check this stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cheykc)